# What is the latest version of django that comes bundled with gae?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

What is the latest version of Django that comes bundled with GAE SDK?
When I downloaded the sdk, it has both 0.96 and 1.2 versions of django in lib.
When I run my application it uses 0.96 version rather than 1.2. I'm not able to use csrf middleware. Do I need to copy django 1.2 version in my app or am I missing some configuration in gae  to make it use 1.2 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `use_library` call somewhere in your application, before your Django import statements to tell GAE which library you wish to use.

See the [Third-party Python Libraries Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to use Django 1.2 is to include the line

```
webapp_django_version='1.2'
```

in `appengine_config.py`.

It's underdocumented at the moment, but has the effect of doing the `use library` for you when you import `webapp`.